# Can i make call to webservice when App is running in background

Tags: ios

I need to make this call to web service over a period of time interval like after 10 min the application went to the background. Can I make call to web service from app when App is running on background? Is there any other way to get some latest data when app is running background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible in iOS6.x or lesser unless your application is has specific requirement to run in background like locations, Voip, music etc...

However this is possible with iOS7, please consider having a look at this [tutorial on Background Fetching](http://redth.info/ios7-recipe-background-fetching/)

Comment: Thank you... i read doc...i will try this for ios7 build..as at present i can not update my app for ios7 however i run on Xcode for ios base SDK6.1... for now i have to go with flow....

Comment: @user2813740 can you share your experience with us? can u call web services in background? How much time it working?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this in background mode. There are few services that can be used in background.

1. **Location updates** : The app keeps users informed of their location, even while it is running in the background.
2. **VOIP :** The app provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection.
3. **Audio :** The app plays audible content to the user or records audio while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or video content using AirPlay.)

Comment: and there is the new "background fetch" mode in iOS 7