# Can the Phone Gap pause event trigger a REST call

Tags: ios, events, cordova, onpause

The Phone Gap [events documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events) states

```
any calls to the Cordova API or to native plugins that go through Objective-C 
do not work
```

Can anyone tell me if a REST call to a web service falls under this category?

Comment: do you want to call webservice on pause event fires. right ?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in iOS6.x or lesser unless your application is has specific requirement to run in background like locations, Voip, music etc...

pause event calls when the app goes in background or another app opens.

Please check this link.

[Can i make call to webservice when App is running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000763/can-i-make-call-to-webservice-when-app-is-running-in-background)